# Sum of an array in which the array is a property of a property in the outer object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, lodash

```
{
    'Edsger W. Dijkstra': [ // o
      { author: 'Edsger W. Dijkstra', likes: 5 },
      { author: 'Edsger W. Dijkstra', likes: 10 }
    ],
    'Benizio Mauritez': [
      { author: 'Benizio Mauritez', likes: 12 },
      { author: 'Benizio Mauritez', likes: 8 }
    ]
  }
```

I have this object which in this case, represents users from a blog in which, I am trying to merge a single author with their total likes already merged, e.g:

```
{
    [
        author: Edsger W. Dijkstra,
        likes: 15
    ],
    [
        author: Benizio Mauritez, 
        likes: 20
    ],
}
```

How can I do this? I've already trying reducing their props (Got stucked at re-assigning or creating a new prop out of that), tried lodash's sumBy function so if someone can enlight me on how to do this, I would be very much appreciating it!, many thanks
!

Comment: What does it mean `[likes: 15]`? Iguess it's incorrect syntax

Comment: Yup, I've already corrected the expected answer, for some reason it posted the wrong formatted expected object

Comment: Are the records unique?

Comment: Yes, they are unique, the outer property is in charge of displaying all the posts a user has so if there are 5 posts of for example djikstra, they will be contained on the prop of the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through the authors in your 'input' object, and produce an 'output' object where you sum the 'likes' of the related array...

Something like this:

```js
input = {
    'Edsger W. Dijkstra': [ // o
      { author: 'Edsger W. Dijkstra', likes: 5 },
      { author: 'Edsger W. Dijkstra', likes: 10 }
    ],
    'Benizio Mauritez': [
      { author: 'Benizio Mauritez', likes: 12 },
      { author: 'Benizio Mauritez', likes: 8 }
    ]
  };

output = Object.keys(input).map(key => {
 return { author: key, likes: input[key].reduce((a, b) => a + b['likes'], 0) };
})

console.log(output);
```

---

To give a bit more explanation:

`Object.keys(input)` will give you an array of the authors in the 'input' object.

```js
console.log(Object.keys(input));
//["Edsger W. Dijkstra", "Benizio Mauritez"]
```

You can then use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to create a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
output = Object.keys(input).map(key => {
 console.log(input[key]);
})

/*
[{
  author: "Edsger W. Dijkstra",
  likes: 5
}, {
  author: "Edsger W. Dijkstra",
  likes: 10
}]
[{
  author: "Benizio Mauritez",
  likes: 12
}, {
  author: "Benizio Mauritez",
  likes: 8
}]
*/
```

Then finally using the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method on the inner array (the array referenced of each key) to sum the 'likes'.

Comment: Removed ['likes'] and worked like a charm, you guys are lifesavers, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick lodash solution (if you need lodash). You will get an array of objects

```
const data = {
    'Edsger W. Dijkstra': [
        { author: 'Edsger W. Dijkstra', likes: 5 },
        { author: 'Edsger W. Dijkstra', likes: 10 }
    ],
    'Benizio Mauritez': [
        { author: 'Benizio Mauritez', likes: 12 },
        { author: 'Benizio Mauritez', likes: 8 }
    ]
}

const result = []

for (const key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const element = data[key];
        const groupedElements= lodash(element).groupBy('author')
        const resultOfReduction = groupedElements.map((objs, key) => ({
            author: key,
            likes: lodash.sumBy(objs, 'likes')
        })).value();

        result.push(resultOfReduction[0])
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

The result will be an array of objects (as I assumed based on your example, but your example has a syntax error, but I believe, based on that you will be able to translate the result in the format what you need, if not - let us know =))

```
[
  { author: 'Edsger W. Dijkstra', likes: 15 },
  { author: 'Benizio Mauritez', likes: 20 }
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the lodash answer, I am currently learning how to use it (this input is actually a returned value from a groupBy lodash function, but It didn't worked quite well for me, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I find your initial structure somewhat strange, given that you've pulled the author up into the above object and sorted the author's blog post metadata objects into those lists. Unless I misunderstand, and there is potentially the wrong author's blog post metadata objects under the author's key within the outer object.

At any rate, you should be able to solve this with a loop and a map/reduce.

```js
const postMetadata = {
    "Edsger W. Dijkstra": [
        {
            author: "Edsger W. Dijkstra",
            likes: 5
        },
        {
            author: "Edsger W. Dijkstra",
            likes: 10
        }
    ],
    "Benizio Mauritez": [
        {
            author: "Benizio Mauritez",
            likes: 12
        },
        {
            author: "Benizio Mauritez",
            likes: 8
        }
    ]
};

// result will be a mapping from author to total likes, which is kinda the structure you've described.
const result = {};
for (let author in postMetadata) {
    let summedLikes = postMetadata[author]
        .map(postMeta => postMeta.likes)
        .reduce((sum, curr) => sum + curr);
    // Do something with summedLikes here
    // for example
    result[author] = summedLikes;
}
```

So what I do here is take your initial structure, I loop through each author, and then for each author's blog post metadata object, I use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) to just get an array of their `likes` values, and then I use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to perform a summing function in order to get the total across each blog post metadata object.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation, it does makes sense and It claread a lot of my head, just like the other guys, thanks a lot for taking your time to answer my questions and I apologize for the weird formatting, somehow it wasn't what I expected as the format but you got the idea anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have come with an answer this is how it looks like

```
[
  {
    "author": "Edsger W. Dijkstra",
    "likes": 15
  },
  {
    "author": "Benizio Mauritez",
    "likes": 20
  }
]
```

I have provided the explanation in the code segment hopefully it helps.
Basically I have used **Object.keys** which allows you to use Array higher-order function like *** map, reduce, filter...etc***, and then used **reduce** to add the likes for each user and then finally return the object with the desired data.

Hopefully, this helps

- Links to know more about

***Object.keys***: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

***Array.prototype.reduce:*** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

***Array.prototype.map:*** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```js
let obj = {
    'Edsger W. Dijkstra': [ 
      { author: 'Edsger W. Dijkstra', likes: 5 },
      { author: 'Edsger W. Dijkstra', likes: 10 }
    ],
    'Benizio Mauritez': [
      { author: 'Benizio Mauritez', likes: 12 },
      { author: 'Benizio Mauritez', likes: 8 }
    ]
  }
 
 /* 
 1) Using Object.keys helps to traverse all the keys in an Object
 2) Then as the value for the available keys is also array we can use reduce to add the likes
 Note: If you don't know about reduce read the article on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce
 
 3) As map returns an new array the ans variable will hold an array with returned objects
 */
let ans = Object.keys(obj).map((item)=>{  
                        let count=  obj[item].reduce((acc,current)=> acc + current.likes,0); 
                        return {'author':item,'likes':count}
                        });

console.log(ans)
```

Comment: Clean solution, I just watched this and I appreciate a lot your explanation to me, I do know reduce and higher order functions but the thought of traversing an array as property melted my mind, so your explanation clears a lot of my mind, Thanks a lot for taking your time to explain your procedure to me, will be using recalling it

Comment: You are welcome @maurirlz. I'm glad that I was able to help you in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the object with `_.map()`, use the `key` (2nd param) as the author. Get the `likes` by getting the sum of the `likes` using `_.sumBy()`:

```js
const obj = {"Edsger W. Dijkstra":[{"author":"Edsger W. Dijkstra","likes":5},{"author":"Edsger W. Dijkstra","likes":10}],"Benizio Mauritez":[{"author":"Benizio Mauritez","likes":12},{"author":"Benizio Mauritez","likes":8}]}
  
const result = _.map(obj, (v, author) => ({
  author,
  likes: _.sumBy(v, 'likes')
}))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```